# Calculate Months within a Date Range and Add to a Table

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to calculate the months within a Date Range and Add the list to a table. The following is the code I have. It breaks down on the line where it is bolded below. Please help me understand what the error is.

```
Public Function MonthsDtRg() As Integer

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim MonDtRg As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim FirstDay As Variant

StDate = Forms!PBCIncSum!StDate
EndDate = Forms!PBCIncSum!EndDate
MonDtRg = Month(StDate)
NMon = DateDiff("m", StDate, EndDate) + 1
FirstDay = DateSerial(Year(StDate), Month(StDate), 1)
i = 0
j = 0

Set dbs = CurrentDb

**Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("MonDtRg", OpenDynaset)**

Do While i < NMon

     i = i + 1
     rs.AddNew
     rs(j).Value = MonDtRg
     rs.Update
     j = j + 1
     FirstDay = DateAdd("m", 1, FirstDay)
     MonDtRg = Month(FirstDay)

Loop

End Function
```

Comment: You said: "It breaks down on the line where it is bolded below." but nothing appears to be emboldened?

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs: It's the line enclosed in **..**.

Comment: There is no *OpenDynaset* value for [OpenRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195231.aspx) method but *dbOpenDynaset*.